# Connect to vSwitch using another NIC interface

Tags: virtualization, vmware

Is it possible to connect a computer's NIC interface directly to an ESXi host NIC interface and add the NIC interface to the existing vSwitch to make them one network?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't have any other other physical NICs attached to the vSwitch you should be able to do that with one PC, but not with a second.

If the vSwitch is alreay connected to a physical NIC then you could create another vSwitch for your new physical NIC, and then create a VM bridging the two vSwitches.  You'll have to use a promiscuous mode port group on both vSwitches I don't know what sort of performance you'd get out of that sort of setup but for a lab or PoC it should be OK.

Comment: Is bridging vSwitches possible in ESXI? I not sure if bridging vSwitches was possible in ESXi, not even tried to setup though. If bridging would be a possiblity what are the steps. Could also a vSphere Distributed Switch could be an another option for this task? Thanks

Comment: It's not native in ESXi.  You have to create say a Linux VM and configure bridging on that.  The Linux VM interfaces will have to be connected to a promiscuous mode portgroup on each vSwitch.  I've done this for lab use and it works.  I haven't played around with a distributed vSwitch, but I don't see that it would help here.  The vSwitch uplinks to the physical NICs are not really normal switch ports.  They have a sense of direction and in-built loop prevention,  but bridging two vSwitches overcomes this limitation.